# How to update a row in a multi-column XTS object?

Tags: r, xts

Given a single-column xts object, I can update a row like this:

```
library(xts)
a=xts(1:5,Sys.Date()+1:5)
b=xts(77:77,Sys.Date()+2)
a[index(b)]=b
```

But once I have 2+ rows it fails with "*number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length*":

```
a=xts(1:5,Sys.Date()+1:5);colnames(a)='x';a$y=11:15
b=xts(77:77,Sys.Date()+2);colnames(b)='x';b$y=78:78
a[index(b)]=b
```

How should I update a single row in an xts object?

For the moment I have this hack:

```
a$x[index(b)]=b$x
a$y[index(b)]=b$y
```

Is there a better way?

**Expected Result:**

```
> a
            x  y
2012-12-24  1 11
2012-12-25 77 78
2012-12-26  3 13
2012-12-27  4 14
2012-12-28  5 15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a comma in your subsetting command:

```
a=xts(1:5,Sys.Date()+1:5);colnames(a)='x';a$y=11:15
b=xts(77:77,Sys.Date()+2);colnames(b)='x';b$y=78:78
a[index(b),]=b
```

Comment: a[index(b),] <- b , here changes the first index of a and not where index(a) == index(b), isn't?

Comment: @agstudy: it works fine for me using xts currently on CRAN (0.8-8).

Comment: Thanks, I've confirmed it works. (I see I was confused by commas and brackets in R again!)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I have same version. Maybe because we don't have the same time zone. I update my answer to show wwhat I have when I use your method.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to use `coredata`, to manipulate matrix

```
    coredata(a)[index(a)==index(b)] <- coredata(b)

> a
            x  y
2012-12-24  1 11
2012-12-25 77 78
2012-12-26  3 13
2012-12-27  4 14
2012-12-28  5 15
```

I would prefer to use a[index(b),]=b as mentioned in the other answer , but for some reasons when I use it I don't have the same result. (It changes the first date not the second one)

```
 a=xts(1:5,Sys.Date()+1:5);colnames(a)='x';a$y=11:15
> b=xts(77:77,Sys.Date()+2);colnames(b)='x';b$y=78:78
> a[index(b),]=b
> a
            x  y
2012-12-23 77 78
2012-12-24  2 12
2012-12-25  3 13
2012-12-26  4 14
2012-12-27  5 15
```

with

```
> b
            x  y
2012-12-24 77 78
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your second case. I tried first with no TZ set, then with `Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")`. Can you show `str(a)` and `str(b)`? I'm running version 0.8-8 of xts, 1.7-9 of zoo, and 2.15.2 of R.